# How to create a counter for sessions in Java

Tags: java, session, counter

I have a Java application that accepts socket requests and I need to make a counter that resets to 0 upon reaching 249.

I tried using the `Preferences` approach but it seems not working for me.
I am now desperate on using the read/write file approach which is not efficient.
Any good suggestions?

Requirement is like this:

Request 1 : counter = 1
Request 2 : counter = 2 
..
Request 250 : counter = 0

Comment: Description of the problem seems to be insufficient. Does your counter have to be persistent? Would a simple `AtomicInteger` shared between threads work?

Comment: Is this a question about persistence?  If not, you can do it in memory.  If you are looking for data persistence, you can look at databases in addition to the file system and Java preferences.  You can also look at in-memory databases like [redis](https://redis.io/)

Comment: I only need a counter that is incremented every session